# Add a new value in Regedit through external system

Tags: powershell

I am adding a registry to regedit to enable an application to be  used as Remote app, currently I am [adding the values manually](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/de-DE/84393b01-295e-4c4f-9477-b8b45a8e297b/how-to-setup-remoteapp-mode-for-some-application-in-windows-10-professional?forum=win10itprosetup).

> 1. Locate to this entry:
>
>    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows
>      NT\CurrentVersion\Terminal Server\TSAppAllowList
> 2. Navigate to fDisabledAllowList value in the right pane, set its value as "1".
> 3. Add new key under TSAppAllowList, named Applications.
> 4. Add new key under Applications, named anything you want(here is "123456").
> 5. Create two new String Values for "123456", named "Name" and "Path".  Name: Notepad Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe

Now I want to do this remotely.
My idea is to make a management system So that I can add a new value in the regedit remotely from the server(other computers) without accessing it.

I want to send some command from the management system server with required values so the system can add new value in regedit and I see the added application on the server.

Is it possible through powershell?

Can I add a new registry to the regedit remotely by using some background service? Any idea from where I can start and which technologies I can use?

Comment: add a comment before downvoting. Everyone is not expert in everything

Comment: All is explained by Snak3d0c comment below his own answer. That's why your question receives downvotes. You're asking (politely) for others to write your script and that's not the purpose of StackOverflow, it's not a scripting service as no one is paid for this but is here to help those who show search efforts before asking. Refer to **[ask]**

Comment: People bother to downvote and write negative comments but cant gives an idea. It is clearly written  I am asking for an overall idea and about which tech to use. How will I know what I am searching is wrong or right. Nothing is explanied below the ans.

Comment: Did you search with some basics keywords in Google like _powershell remote registry_ and see by yourself if you can find what you're looking for? I just did it and found tens of tutorials that can answer your question. You can ask questions, none are sillies, but you ask here to have an idea before even searching on search engines or on StackOverflow itself if it has been already solved. For me discussion is closed now.

Comment: The best is to ignore if you can not ans, For a non-English speaker, it is easier to google than to write a full question.if I had found something I would have never asked. Thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible with Powershell.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName  $computer -ScriptBlock {

$Reg = "Registry::HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\...."

Set-ItemProperty -Path "$Reg" -Name PATH -Value $x

}
```

Comment: how does it work. Will the script run in the background and will get called by an external service? If a want to run it through other computer?

Comment: I'm not gonna write your code or do the research for you, that's not what stackoverflow is about. Given the commands i gave you, you should be capable of answering these questions yourself.

Comment: It uses [Powershell remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/running-remote-commands?view=powershell-5.1), we're not going to explain this to you as there is plenty of information on this available already if you search yourself.

Comment: I am not asking you to code for me. I am just asking for pointers- You can just say use powershell remoting and make connection remotely.use etc. Neither I am asking you to do research for me. It takes just one minute to say use this or follow this link. What is the point of this site if every one is always discouraging